# Validate an argument value based on another argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments, argparse

I want to validate a argument based on the value of another argument.

```
SampleScript.py

    def parse_args():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('-a', '--arg1', help="Year-Month or Year")
        parser.add_argument('-b', '--arg2', help="Needs Month from argument arg1", action="store_true")
        args = parser.parse_args()
        return args

     def main():
        args = parse_args()

     if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Value for `arg1` can be in format `YYYY` or `YYYY-MM`. However, when the `arg2` is set, I want to make sure that the value for `arg1` passed is in format 'YYYY-MM' and not 'YYYY'.

i.e when I run `python SampleScript.py -a 2011`, the program should work fine.
    when I run `python SampleScript.py -a 2011 -b`, the program should throw an error since `-a` is not in `YYYY-MM` format

Is it possible to do such validation using `argparse` ?

Comment: Using [`parse_known_args`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args) is acceptable for your use case? It allows to parse the arguments in more than one step. Otherwise I see no way of achieving what you want *and* letting the user specify `-a` and `-b` without order restrictions. If you impose the user to specify `-b` before `-a` then a custom action would be enough.

Comment: In theory you could write a custom `type` or `action` to do this, but if `-a` and `-b` can occur in either order, the logic will be complicated.  Doing your own check after `parse_args` will be simpler, since both values are available in the `namespace`.  You could still use `parser.error` to produce a standardized error message.

Comment: As presented `-b` does not give any additional information about the users intention.  You could just deduce its value from the `-a` value, and never have a conflict.  But then this could be part of a larger interface where `-b` has an independent meaning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-argument validation in argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49000217/cross-argument-validation-in-argparse)