# Python argparse for script arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

Below is the example code for argparse in  python script.

```
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-a','--example-a ',  action='store_true', help='--example-a ')
group.add_argument('-b','--example-b' action='store_true', help= '--example-b')
group.add_argument('-c', '--example-c', action='store_true', help= '--example-c')
group.add_argument('-d', '--directory', action='store_true', help= 'to input directory')
```

Please help me how to add argument if they specify '-d' '--directory' they must input directory path

and if they specify any option like  -a, -b, -c with option -d  they must specify directory path as input.

Comment: If `-d` is a default `store`, it will take the path as an argument.

Comment: -d is not a default. Directory path i have specified internally.  In case they chosen -d to specify custom directory path

Comment: I mean: `group.add_argument('-d', '--directory', help= ' directory')`.  Also, `-d` can't be used with one of the others; they are all mutually exclusive.

Comment: How to define to use -d with other options example -a -d or -ad and specify directory

Comment: Define the `-d` outside of the group.  Let the user specify a directory regardless of what the other flags say.

Comment: -d is optional, in case -d is specified in command line then any one flags must specif in this case (-a, -b or -c)

Comment: Test for that kind  of coordination after parsing.

Comment: I give it up, I will go for if else

Comment: [Cross-argument validation in argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49000217)

Comment: Thanks hpaulj, finally I have achieved with argparse. Last thing i need help is .i need to add one argument which should not apper in  --help or -h output

Comment: Check the docs for `help=argparse.SUPPRESS`.

Comment: Great, It works Thanks a lot